/tmp/chromium: cannot execute binary file in AWS lambda
I'm trying to generate PDF from html templates. I'm using a layer with puppeteer-core and @sparticuz/chromium-min libraries. I added this layer in a Lambda function.
As far as I know this chromium-min library doesn't have some files that are needed. So you need to download them. Following the example of this link: https://github.com/Sparticuz/chromium/blob/master/examples/remote-min-binary/index.js
I'm still not able to render the html. I got the following error:
/tmp/chromium: cannot execute binary file
I'm using Lambda with Nodejs 16.x as runtime
I have tried the two approaches Sparticuz has in the github examples, getting the missing files from githib link and download the layer version and add it to the lambda
Lambda configuration:
Runtime: Nodejs 16.x
Arch: arm64
AWS Layer with the following libs: puppeteer-core and @sparticuz/chromium-min

I am running into a similar issue, and not sure if this will help you, but I don't think @sparticuz/chromium supports ARM architecture yet

Yeah, I saw that. Actually my friend was able to run chronium in a lambda using  x86 arch. This is the repo that you can use as reference: https://github.com/glnicolas/puppeteer-pdf-nodejs-lambda
